# Botman Laravel for Telegram - Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I am creating a bot on telegram with laravel. The bot works fine. My issue is the previous buttons created are dismissed when a new question follows up.

When user selects 1. Test My Account, a new question with buttons is created. But the previous button which is `Test My Account` and `Delete My Account` disappears from the message thread.

How do i keep all buttons created in the thread ?

**Controller**

```
$question = Question::create("Hi. What do you need ?")
            ->fallback('Unable to ask question')
            ->callbackId('ask_reason')
            ->addButtons([
                Button::create('1. Test My Account')->value('test'),
                Button::create('2. Delete My Account')->value('delete'),

     return $this->ask($question, function (Answer $answer) {

        if ($answer->isInteractiveMessageReply()) {

            if ($answer->getValue() === 'test') {

               $question_1 = Question::create("Will you like to continue ?")

            ->fallback('Unable to ask question')

            ->callbackId('ask_reason')

            ->addButtons([
                Button::create('1. Continue')->value('continue'),
            }           

            ]);
```